# How to unit test a python method with double underscore?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to write a unit test for a python class that has a method similar to this:

```
@staticmethod
def __some_method():
    doSomething...
```

The issue I'm facing is that the __some_method doesn't show up in the unit test file. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't show up"?

Comment: 'Private' methods (double underscored) have their names mangled. So the short answer is you're actually looking for `MyClass._MyClass__mymethod()`.